# Procurar uma expressão em diversos elementos de uma lista

Tags: r

Gente, estou com um problema. Tenho 200 planilhas com alguns dados de uma pesquisa, e estou importando no R e, por elas estarem com colunas diferentes, atribuo a cada elemento da minha lista uma planilha diferente. 
Eu preciso procurar um nome que pode estar em qualquer uma das planilha e que me retorne em qual elemento da lista que esse nome está. Como eu posso fazer isso?

Por exemplo, descobrir onde está o "José da Silva":

```
df1 <- data.frame(nome = c("José da Silva", "Maria da Silva"),
              idade = c(45, 54))
df2 <- data.frame(nome_completo = c("Mauro Pereira", "João Paulo"),
              idade = c(30, 12))

lista <- list()
lista[[1]] <- df1
lista[[2]] <- df2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
library(purrr)

buscar_nome <- function(lista, nome) {
  map_lgl(lista, ~any(nome %in% .x[[1]])) %>% which()  
}

# > buscar_nome(lista, "Maria da Silva")
# [1] 1
# > buscar_nome(lista, "Mauro Pereira")
# [1] 2
```

Uma suposição importante que estou fazendo é a de que o nome buscado está na primeira coluna do data.frame... Isso pode ser modificado da seguinte forma para procurar em todas as colunas (porém perdendo eficiência).

```
buscar_nome <- function(lista, nome) {
  map_lgl(lista, ~any(nome %in% as.matrix(.x))) %>% which()  
}
```

Comment: Daniel, acabei de melhorar um pouco a sua função para conseguir encontrar trechos de nome, quando eu não tenho o nome exato da pessoa: 

buscar_nome2 <- function(lista, nome) {
  map_lgl(lista, ~any(grep(nome, as.matrix(.x)))) %>% which()  
}

Answer (score 8):

Utilizando a função `which` dentro de `lapply`

```
lapply(lista, function(x) which(x == "José da Silva"))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
integer(0)
```

Essa é uma opção para pesquisar um termo exato, como no seu exemplo o "José da Silva"

Comment: Essa resposta é boa, mas no meu caso eu tenho uma lista com 250 elementos, precisava de algo que me retornasse apenas a posição onde a expressão está.

Answer (score 5):

Fiz uma pequena alteração nos seus dados pra aumentar o número de casos:

```
df1 <- data.frame(nome = c("José da Silva", "Maria da Silva"),
              idade = c(45, 54))
df2 <- data.frame(nome_completo = c("Mauro Pereira", "João Paulo", "João Pedro"),
              idade = c(30, 12, 1))
df3 <- data.frame(renda = c(1, 2, 3),
              idade = c(3, 2, 9),
              nome_do_cabra = c("Antônio Augusto", "João Marcos", "João Ivo"))

lista <- list()
lista[[1]] <- df1
lista[[2]] <- df2
lista[[3]] <- df3
```

Veja se essa função resolve o seu problema. Não está muito eficiente (loop dentro de loop... etc), mas creio que faz trabalho.

```
procura_nome <- function(x, pattern){
    list_result <- list()
    element_list_i = 1
    for(j in 1:length(x)){
            for(k in 1:ncol(x[[j]])){
                    linhas_result <- grep(x = x[[j]][,k], pattern = pattern)
                    if(length(linhas_result) > 0){
                            list_result[[element_list_i]] <- cbind(j, k, linhas_result)
                            element_list_i = element_list_i + 1
                    }
            }
    }
    if(length(list_result) >0 ){
            matrix_result <- purrr::reduce(list_result, rbind)
            df_result     <- as.data.frame(matrix_result)
            names(df_result) <- c("numero_lista", "numero_coluna", "numero_linha")
            return(df_result)
    }else{
            return(NULL)
    }
}
```

Como a função de busca por string usada internamente é a `grep`, você pode procurar por nomes de maneira não exata. É possível aprimorar, claro, pra deixar case-insensitive, ignorar acentos etc.

O resultado é um data.frame com uma coluna indicando o número do elemento dentro da lista, outra indicando a coluna do data.frame e uma terceira indicando a linha, tal como o seguinte:

```
procura_nome(lista, "João")
###   numero_lista numero_coluna numero_linha
### 1            2             1            2
### 2            2             1            3
### 3            3             3            2
### 4            3             3            3
```

Comment: Rogério, essa função não está me retornando a linha e a coluna certa e eu não consigo ver onde dá para ajeitar isso